# Driver not found error in Qt

Tags: mysql, qt

I was trying to connect mysql with Qt 5.2.1. I ran a program but got the error

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QPSQL QPSQL7
```

I ran the following command on terminal to solve the problem.

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5sql5-mysql
```

But problem remained unsolved.

The code is as follows.

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtSql/QSql>
#include <QTableWidget>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlRecord>
#include <QtSql/QSqlDriver>
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc,argv);
    QTableWidget* table = new QTableWidget();
    table->setWindowTitle("Connect to Mysql Database Example");

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    qDebug()<<"abc";
    db.setHostName("192.168.11.3");
    db.setDatabaseName("menudb");
    db.setUserName("root");
    db.setPassword("test");
    if (!db.open())
    {
      QMessageBox::critical(0, QObject::tr("Database Error"),
                 db.lastError().text());
    }

    QSqlQuery query("SELECT * FROM test");

    table->setColumnCount(query.record().count());
    table->setRowCount(query.size());

    int index=0;
    while (query.next())
    {
    table->setItem(index,0,new QTableWidgetItem(query.value(0).toString()));
    table->setItem(index,1,new QTableWidgetItem(query.value(1).toString()));
    index++;
    }

    table->show();
    qDebug()<<"charu";
    return app.exec();
}
```

Please help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded    
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QPSQL QPSQL7
```

That means that you have the MySql plugin driver for Qt, but probably you don't have the MySql client lib (libmysqlclient.so).
So, make sure that you have libmysqlclient.so in your library path.
To check the dependencies of the plugin use:
    objdump -p /PathToQt/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so | grep NEEDED

Comment: Yes exactly I dont have this file. How can I get this file?

Comment: Install MySql or MariaDB.

Comment: MySql is already installed I can create tables and run sql commands on terminal. But unable to locate the above file at specifies location

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Operating System is Ubuntu14.04

Comment: sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev

Comment: On applying this command it shows that it is already installed

Comment: Ok, what "objdump -p /PathToQt/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so | grep NEEDED" shows you?

Comment: I got following output:
objdump: invalid option -- '/'